# How to implement Jasny Bootstrap Off Canvas menu with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, jasny-bootstrap

I try to implement Jasny Bootstrap Off Canvas menu with wordpress with wp-bootstrap-navwalker. The slide effect works great but it's empty. You could see [the Jasny Bootstrap Off Canvas menu here](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#offcanvas)

Here is my code :

```
 <nav id="myNavmenu" class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left offcanvas" role="navigation">

<?php /* Primary navigation */
wp_nav_menu( array(
'menu' => 'top_menu',
'depth' => 3,
'container' => 'div',
'container_class'   => 'offcanvas',
'container_id'      => 'myNavmenu',
'menu_class'        => 'nav navmenu navmenu-default',
//Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
'  walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
);
?>
</nav>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-      target="#myNavmenu" data-canvas="body">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
</div>
```

I think my problem comes from the menu class, container class and container id.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was an old css style in my style.css who enter in conflict with the Jasny Bootstrap Menu.

Shame on me. :)